# Bulk Update RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Good Morning,  We are trying to find a way to do a Bulk update of a couple thousand documents in RavenDB.   This is the first time we have done this as the DB is provided by a third party and they are not sure either on how to do this.

Essentially we have 1000's of records that look like this one below:

```
{
    "VPOId": 8,
    "Description": "VPO 8",
    "AreaId": "93",
    "AreaDisplay": "Area",
    "Address": "Address",
    "JobId": "109201005111",
    "JobDisplay": "Address",
    "TradeId": "19",
    "TradeDisplay": "Finishing",
    "VarianceId": "V70",
    "VarianceDisplay": "V70 - Trade Change",
    "SupplierId": "104095",
    "SupplierDisplay": "Vendor Name",
    "SupplierBackChargeId": null,
    "SupplierBackChargeDisplay": null,
    "IssuedDate": "2017-08-14T00:00:00.0000000",
    "SearchTerms": " 109201005111 ",
    "AccountId": "d740eb47-137d-e711-80d4-00505681128f",
    "Active": true,
    "DivisionDisplay": "010"
```

we need to mass update the Search Terms and the JobID Perferable from an our EXCEL spreadsheet mapping document.  I have tried the export and import csv but that just seems to create new records vs updating the old ones or do we have a way that we can do that.
......

Answer (score -1):

If your input is CSV, you'll need to write a script that does this.
You can do that in Python or C#.